# Word/short phrase for "timespan has not yet started"

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a word or short phrase for telling that a timespan has not yet started? In this case, I want to apply it to licenses, which have a timespan within which they are valid.

- If the current time is after the license's validity period, the license is **expired**.
- If the current time is within the license's validity period, the license is **valid**.
- If the current time is before the license's validity period, the license is ______.

Comment: "the licence commences on ..."; "... not yet commenced"; "valid from ..."; "yet to start".

Comment: ... not yet effective.

Comment: There isn't a single word for it.

Comment: No idea if this fits your context, but the question reminds me of a term from legal parlance - *in abeyance.*

Comment: @Autoresponder [Abeyance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abeyance) has the idea of *disuse* or *suspension* rather than 'pre-validity'. There's an expectation that something more substantial than the passage of time is needed before it's (again) available.

Comment: I'd suggest *pre-contractual*, but there are issues (existing but different [legal definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pre-contract?q=precontract); also, the contract may be in force even though the licence period hasn't commenced). The licence is actually *invalid* before the start of the validity period, though *invalid* doesn't carry the idea that it is about to become valid.

Comment: @Lawrence. That might well be the legal sense for all I know about legalese. And reading your comment brought to mind *in gestation,* which seems to be the gist of the sense OP is getting at, but it's not a well-worn or a standard phrase.

Comment: premature?  It has been conceived but not achieved proper birth.

Comment: presumptive?  It might be revoked before attaining applicability.

Comment: The more common usage is to call it an "advance licence" -- try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that the license is **unbegun**.

(Collins Dictionary)

> [Unbegun](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unbegun) - not commenced; not yet started

Comment: I've chosen this, since it comes closed to what "validity time has not yet begun". In my context, the license is a software license that was already paid for and given to the customer, so no other steps like approving are necessary before it becomes valid. Also, I like the newspeak-touch of this (1984) :-)

Comment: I've chosen this since it comes closest to what "validity time has not yet begun" means in my context. In this context, the license is a software license that was already paid for and given to the customer, so no other steps like approving are necessary before it becomes valid. Also, I like the newspeak-touch of this (1984) :-) (<- I've corrected the grammar, hopefully)

Comment: Risky: The other, often the primary, sense is "not having a beginning; always existing"

Comment: Isn't there a duty to use commonplace words that the general public will understand here? Isn't the reader in all likelihood going to be confused unless they take a bit of joy out of happening upon fairly esoteric words?

Answer (score 18):

You could use ***pending***

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pending

```
pending  
Also found in: Thesaurus, Medical, Legal, Acronyms, Encyclopedia, Wikipedia.
Related to pending: sale pending
pend·ing  (pĕn′dĭng)
adj.
1. Not yet decided or settled; awaiting conclusion or confirmation.
2. Impending; imminent.
prep.
1. While in the process of; during.
2. While awaiting; until.
```

or, ***upcoming***

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/upcoming

```
up·com·ing  (ŭp′kŭm′ĭng)
adj.
Occurring soon; forthcoming.

upcoming (ˌʌpˈkʌmɪŋ)
adj
coming soon; forthcoming

up•com•ing (ˈʌpˌkʌm ɪŋ) 
adj.
coming up; about to take place, appear, or be presented: the upcoming spring fashions.
```

Comment: To me, *pending* could imply that it is still awaiting approval or similar.  I read the question as meaning that the licence has been granted/approved but it's validity period has not yet commenced - but I may be wrong!

Comment: I think you're right that it's ambiguous - pending can mean either "Upcoming" or "Awaiting approval".  In a context where there could potentially be an aspect of waiting for approval then that ambiguity probably makes it a bad choice.

Comment: +1.*Pending* seems like the right term, with the available context.

Comment: Upcoming conveys the "future" quality, without the "not yet decided" connotation of Pending.  +1 for Upcoming.

Comment: It's neither pending not impending by any definition of the terms.

Answer (score 3):

Try **prospective** as in "prospective license," "valid license" and "expired license."

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prospective)

> effective in the future.

Comment: I would say that *prospective* has the same problem as *pending*, as discussed in the comments under the answer from @MaxWilliams. You've actually confirmed that by giving one meaning  as "*likely to* be or become".

Comment: @TrevorD but that is one of the several meanings. What if i had posted just the first one?

Comment: I would have still made the same comment.  The point is that OP wants a word to clarify a particular status - and therefore IMHO it needs to be **unambiguous**, and I would say that *prospective* **is** ambiguous.  See the response from @MaxWilliams to my earlier comment.

Comment: @TrevorD You are right. I guess op would have to settle for something else.

Comment: @TrevorD So in a nutshell op wants a terse of "the license will be effective soon"  in a word.

Answer (score 3):

Consider **Impending** ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/impending))

> about to happen; imminent

It is basically the "next step up" from pending, where the official outcome is unresolved. Impending means it will happen, just not yet.

Comment: I don't know if this is just due to it often being paired with the word "doom", but "impending" sounds quite threatening, I think.

Answer (score 3):

A few other words not suggested yet:

- the licence is on **stand-by**
- the licence is **awaiting activation**
- the licence is **scheduled**
- the licence is **ready** (which to me implies it's not yet in use)

Answer (score 1):

Consider *poised to begin*.

> **Poise** *verb*
>   1.1 (be poised) Be ready and prepared to do something
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/poise)

Here's an example of the term in use in this sense:

> 6 Razorbacks poised to begin NFL careers this week
>   [- wholehogsports.com](http://www.wholehogsports.com/news/2016/apr/27/banking-on-pick-6-20160427/?f=sports)

When used with an inanimate noun such as a licence or a project, *poised to begin* relates to a metaphorical posture of readiness. Here is an example:

> Pacific NorthWest LNG project poised to begin despite abundant supply
>   [- Brent Jang, The Globe and Mail](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/british-columbia/pacific-northwest-lng-project-poised-to-begin-despite-abundant-supply/article28094599/)

Comment: Poised implies *intention*.  A licence doesn't have intention because it doesn't have a mind.

Comment: @MaxWilliams *Projects* don't have minds either, but they can be *poised to begin*. I've added another example and a note along these lines.

Comment: Hmmm.   Perhaps there's an implication with the usage with projects that it's the project's **team** that is poised, but I take your point.  I still think it's not right for licences.

Answer (score 1):

With a tip of the hat to @vickyace

One often speaks of licences as being *in full force and effect* for one or more periods.

If "valid" = in effect, prior to being valid = not [yet] in effect or not [yet] in force

[effect](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/effect): The condition of being *in full force* or execution; operativeness

Answer (score 1):

"Not yet valid"

Seems the most obvious and explicit, because it implies that as time passes it will become valid. "Not Yet" gives it the element of setting up a timeline.